# Okhttp issue using Retrofit in java

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname ttslive.com not verified:
certificate: sha256/i253ekxmSHEVN5aD4LQN6FPy53jbfY0aasjzLgzzYgc=
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient:     DN: CN=imfitow.com
subjectAltNames: [imfitow.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again by setting your destination URL to `http` or `https`.

Also check that your destination URL supports SSL.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate being served for ttslive.com was for a different domain, imfitow.com, hence the failure.  It has subsequently been fixed so likely your request will succeed now.

```
$ ./cft --host ttslive.com 
CN:     www.ttslive.com
Pin:    sha256/6883961b59af6eb8445adbedf0182885be19f6d710227308ec3f3924c1d6c6d1
SAN:    ttslive.com, www.ttslive.com
Key Usage: DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment
Ext Key Usage: serverAuth, clientAuth
Authority Info Access:
    ocsp: http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
    caIssuers: http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/
Valid:  2020-10-10T07:11:46Z..2021-01-08T07:11:46Z (2 months)
CA: false

CN:     Lets Encrypt Authority X3
Pin:    sha256/60b87575447dcba2a36b7d11ac09fb24a9db406fee12d2cc90180517616e8a18
SAN:    <N/A>
Key Usage: DigitalSignature, KeyCertSign, CRLSign
Authority Info Access:
    ocsp: http://isrg.trustid.ocsp.identrust.com
    caIssuers: http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
Valid:  2016-03-17T16:40:46Z..2021-03-17T16:40:46Z (4 months)
CA: true Max Intermediate: 0

CN:     DST Root CA X3 (signed by locally-trusted root)
Pin:    sha256/563b3caf8cfef34c2335caf560a7a95906e8488462eb75ac59784830df9e5b2b
SAN:    <N/A>
Key Usage: KeyCertSign, CRLSign
Valid:  2000-09-30T21:12:19Z..2021-09-30T14:01:15Z (11 months)
CA: true
```